# Insert small dictionary like {1:23, 2:45, 3:17} into a column of SQL database table in Postgres using python language

Tags: python, sql, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table having one varchar type column and 2 json type columns, which i created using:

```
create table global_records(
     cattle_id varchar(255) not null primary key, 
     step_count json, 
     speed json
);
```

I now want to insert values like this using python:

```
INSERT INTO 
       global_records(cattle_id, step_count, speed) 
VALUES ('cattle_A', '{1: 22, 4: 12}', '{2: 24, 6: 98}');
```

For which i wrote a string in python like this to execute:

```
cattle_id = 'cattle_A'
step_count_dict = {1: 22, 4: 12}
speed_dict = {2: 24, 6: 98}

query = "INSERT INTO global_records(cattle_id, step_count, speed) VALUES ('"+cattle_id+"', '" + str(step_count_dict) + "', '" + str(speed_dict) + "'); "
```

But this doesn't work. I am getting following error:

```
invalid input syntax for type json
    LINE 1: ... step_count) values ('cattle_A', '{1: 22}',...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Expected string or "}", but found "1".
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {1...
```

I searched for similar answers but couln't find one. This should be simple.

It should look like this in the table:

```
cattle_id |   step_count   |    speed
----------+----------------+----------------
cattle_A  | {1: 22, 4: 12} | {2: 24, 6: 98}
cattle_B  | {4: 92, 6: 90} | {88: 4, 12: 23}
```

Comment: You are converting your dicts into strings but the type in the sql table is json. are you getting any kind of errors? Maybe a string type would work? EDIT: nvm I think the answer got it

Comment: Have to convert it to string to concatenate it with python query string using + sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `json.dumps` for json data (serializes to string) as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation) and let `psycopg2` do all work and parameter binding:

```
cattle_id = 'cattle_A'
step_count_dict = json.dumps({1: 22, 4: 12})
speed_dict = json.dumps({2: 24, 6: 98})

cur = con.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO global_records(cattle_id, step_count, speed) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
cur.execute(query, (cattle_id, step_count_dict, speed_dict))
con.commit()

cur.execute('Select * from global_records')
print(cur.fetchall())
```

Out:

```
[('cattle_A', {'1': 22, '4': 12}, {'2': 24, '6': 98})]
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!! It worked ! This was eating my brain past 1 day.

Comment: @Vinita Kumari: You might want to accept any answer to mark your question resolved and to help others.

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT compose queries by stitching strings together. This is almost guaranteed to lead to security vulnerabilities.

The psycopg2 library has perfectly good JSON support and there are clear examples in the documentation. Even if you wanted to ignore the JSON support use placeholders in your query.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Good one actually.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against "splicing" your sql query. This could set you up for injection attacks if you make it a habit.

Use the python sql api like this, assuming you have a cursor (`cur`) in the form of `cur.execute('SQL CODE w/ insertions as ? ? ?', (tupel, of, substitutions)`:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO global_records(cattle_id, step_count, speed) VALUES (?,?,?)', (cattle_id, step_count_dict, speed_dict))
```

The database library you are using should be able to figure out how to parse the given variables into the right form to insert your row into the sql database you are using.

Comment: Used this line:
cur.execute('INSERT INTO global_records(cattle_id, step_count) VALUES (?,?)', (cattle_id, step_count_dict))


Got this error:
syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...(cattle_id, step_count) VALUES (?,?)
                                                                    ^

Answer (score -2):

To insert data into a JSON column, you have to ensure that data is in a valid JSON format, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO 
       global_records(cattle_id, step_count, speed) 
VALUES ('cattle_A', '{"1": "22", "4": "12"}', '{"2": "24", "6": "98"}');
```

so you probably have to serialize to JSON format the dictionaries as:

```
import json

cattle_id = 'cattle_A'
step_count_dict = {1: 22, 4: 12}
speed_dict = {2: 24, 6: 98}

query = "INSERT INTO global_records(cattle_id, step_count, speed) VALUES ('"+cattle_id+"', '" + json.dumps(step_count_dict) + "', '" + json.dumps(speed_dict) + "'); "
```

Comment: That + not being there was a mistake here, in my question not in my actual code. But i edited it.

Comment: What is the error message exactly? or in what context?