# How to Insert into a JSONB column in PostgreSQL using python?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2, jsonb

[solved. .... But]

I am inserting some data using python in a PostgreSQL database. The code is working well for any other table. But, when I have a JSONB column and inserting data from an api, this error happend:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO pokeapi(id, body) VALUES (0, {"abilities":[{"abi...
```

[image]

Here is the entire code:

```
import psycopg2
import hidden
import time
import myutils
import requests
import json


secrets = hidden.secrets()
print(secrets)

conn = psycopg2.connect(host=secrets['host'],
        port=secrets['port'],
        database=secrets['database'],
        user=secrets['user'],
        password=secrets['pass'],
        connect_timeout=3)

cur = conn.cursor()

defaulturl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'
print('If you want to restart the spider, run')
print('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pokeapi CASCADE;')
print(' ')

createpokeapi = '''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pokeapi CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pokeapi (id INTEGER, body JSONB);
'''
print(createpokeapi)
cur.execute(createpokeapi)

pkval = int(input('How many rows? : '))
for i in range(0, pkval):
    furl = f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{i+1}/"
    print(furl)
    result = requests.get(furl)
    jsdata = result.text
    print(jsdata)
    sql = f'INSERT INTO pokeapi(id, body) VALUES ({i}, {jsdata} )';
    print(sql)
    cur.execute(sql)
    if i % 5 == 0:
        conn.commit()

print('Closing database connection...')
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

This error is happening at the first insert. No data inserted.
I inserted interger/varchar data types with interger/varchar column instead of JSONB and it works. Tried more than 6 hours searching on google. No luck for my specific problem. What may be the solution ? or any hints ?

My solution so far:

I just changed line 62 and 63:

```
# sql = f'INSERT INTO pokecheckapi(id, body) VALUES ({i}, {jsdata} )';
# cur.execute(sql)
```

to

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO pokecheckapi(id, body) VALUES ( %s, %s )';
cur.execute(sql, (i, jsdata))
```

And it works.
Can i get a good explanation of this ? Anyone ??

Comment: Instead of 6 hours on Google you have tried 5 minutes in the docs [Type adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) in particular [JSON](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json). You should also look at [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) to see the correct way to use parameters in a query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert small dictionary like {1:23, 2:45, 3:17} into a column of SQL database table in Postgres using python language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025708/insert-small-dictionary-like-123-245-317-into-a-column-of-sql-database-ta) ... identical for `JSONB`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, that is the long way around to a solution that is built into `psycopg2`.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks both of you. I have gone with @Maurice's ref. before but made a silly mistake. Now this time i got it.

Comment: I just changed: ` # sql = f'INSERT INTO pokecheckapi(id, body) VALUES ({i}, {jsdata} )'; # cur.execute(sql) ` to `    sql = f'INSERT INTO pokecheckapi(id, body) VALUES ( %s, %s )';    cur.execute(sql, (i, jsdata)) `

Comment: It works because databases have strict rules about the format of values that are passed to queries.  Doing `cursor.execute(sql, vars)` delegates the formatting to the connector package which implements the rules correctly.  F-strings or other string formatting techniques will not reliably produce the correct values.  This is why _every_ official tutorial recommends against string formatting.